# After migration from 1.8.x to 1.9.3 admin image browse button not working

Tags: magento1.9.3

I have migrated my magento from 1.8.x to 1.9.3 but after that magento product image browse file button is not working, if I click browse button it doesn't do anything.

in console I can see error like

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined(…)

I can see already existing images and working fine in both admin and front end.

Comment: Issue fixed, the issue was i am merging the js files so the previous error in js file is blocking the execution, so the class Uploader is not getting initialized

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Please check this file available or not

> /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
>   /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
>   /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/editor.swf
>   /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
>   /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
>   /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/editor.phtml

Comment: in magento 1.9.3 removed flash based uploading images, now it's javascript based so no need of *.swf files

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the Uploader module not being recognized. Try flushing your configuration cache (`System > Cache Management` or `rm -rf var/cache/*`).

Make sure following files are in place and `readable` by the webserver – try retrieving their URLs directly to see if this is the case:

```
js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
```

Ensure file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml` contains

```
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</name></action>
```

If this is the case, flush your layout cache and especially delete your merged JS & CSS file cache (lower left at `System > Cache Management`).

Comment: Tried all, still no luck

Comment: see updated answer